# How to remove variables from rewrited url and keep removed url variables

Tags: php

My index page;

```
<form id="myfom" action="x.php" method="get">
<fieldset>

<select name="a1" id="a1">
<option value="o1">o1</option>
<option value="o2">o2</option>
</select>

<select name="a2" id="a2">
<option value="oo1">oo1</option>
<option value="oo2">oo2</option>
</select>

<select name="a3" id="a3">
<option value="ooo1">ooo1</option>
<option value="ooo2">ooo2</option>
</select>

<select name="a4" id="a4">
<option value="oooo1">oooo1</option>
<option value="oooo2">oooo2</option>
</select>

<select name="a5" id="a5">
<option value="ooooo1">ooooo1</option>
<option value="ooooo2">ooooo2</option>
</select>

<select name="a6" id="a6">
<option value="oooooo1">oooooo1</option>
<option value="oooooo2">oooooo2</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function murl() {
    var grp1 = document.getElementById('a1').options[document.getElementById('a1').selectedIndex].value;
    var grp2 = document.getElementById('a2').options[document.getElementById('a2').selectedIndex].value;
    var grp3 = document.getElementById('a3').options[document.getElementById('a3').selectedIndex].value;
    var grp4 = document.getElementById('a4').options[document.getElementById('a4').selectedIndex].value;
    var grp5 = document.getElementById('a5').options[document.getElementById('a5').selectedIndex].value;
    var grp6 = document.getElementById('a6').options[document.getElementById('a6').selectedIndex].value ;
    var url = "http://www.domain.com/"+grp1+"-"+grp2+"-"+grp3+"-"+grp4+"-"+grp5+"-"+grp6+".html";

    document.forms["myform"].submit();
    window.location.href=url;
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="murl()" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

htaccess file is;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ x.php?a1=$1&a2=$2&a3=$3&a4=$4&a5=$5&a6=$6 [L,QSA]
```

Site is working like this;
http://www.domain.com/a1-a2-a3-a4-a5-a6.html

And here is my question;
I want the url like http://www.domain.com/a1-a2-a3.html

But i also want to get the variables which are a4,a5,a6 on new page (after submitting form to x.php)

Tried many things like RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING},

Any help will be greatful..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, at least not directly. If you remove stuff from the URL, it is gone.

You would have to call a PHP script with the full URL `a1-a2-a3-a4-a5-a6.html`, store a4-a6 in a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), and do a [`header()`](http://www.php.net/header) redirect to `a1-a2-a3.html`. However, that will cause trouble if the same user agent makes multiple request - to fix that, you could also check `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` on the target page.

Both is fairly complicated. Are you sure you need this?

Comment: Wow thanks for fast answer,but should be a way.. how about php session? cant we send invisible variables with get method ?

Comment: @qxygene no, there are no invisible variables with GET. As said, the only way is sessions or checking the referer header from `a1-a2-a3.html` after you've done the redirect. But it's complicated, I wouldn't do it just for the sake of a pretty URL